# JSON (sqlalchemy) vs JSONType (sqlalchemy_utils)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy-utils

I would like to know the difference between the build-in [SQLAlchemy JSON type](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON) and the [JSONType introduced by the plugin SQLAlchemy_utils](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.json)

For me, there seem identical...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, the `JSONType` only uses JSON on Postgres and TEXT on others. The built-in SQLAlchemy `JSON` works on PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite(via [JSON1 Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)) and MS SQL Server.

The `JSONType` was (probably) added before the built-in type was fully implemented.